# JPA createEntityManager NPE JtaStatusHelper.getStatus

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, nullpointerexception

I'm simply unable to inject EntityManagerFactory object from ProfileDBUtil into ProfileManager class where I actually apply the transactions to look for an entry in the database, or update a row and so.

createEntityManager() method throws the exception specified in the end of the entry.

The weird thing is that the same piece of code works for UAT environment while it fails for SIT environment.  All config is the same for both of the environments. Class loader order, shared lib references, module class loaders are the same. 
Both of the environments have the necessary jars in their file system and seem to be loaded successfully in runtime.

What would be the root cause for this problem?

```
  public class ProfileDBUtil {


     private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT = "com.profile.userdb";

     public boolean loadProfile(String memberID) {
      EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT);
      ProfileManager upm = new ProfileManager(emf);
      List < Profile > ProfileList = upm.searchProfile(memberID);
     }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @JPAManager(targetEntity = com.profile.userdb.model.Profile.class)
    public class ProfileManager {


     private EntityManagerFactory emf;

     public ProfileManager() {

     }
     public ProfileManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
      this.emf = emf;
     }

     public void setEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
      this.emf = emf;
     }

     private EntityManager getEntityManager() {
      if (emf == null) {
       throw new RuntimeException("The EntityManagerFactory is null.  This must be passed in to the constructor``");
      }
      return emf.createEntityManager(); // THIS FAILS
     }

    }
```

**Log trace;**

```
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaStatusHelper.getStatus(JtaStatusHelper.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaStatusHelper.isActive(JtaStatusHelper.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransaction.join(CMTTransaction.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.joinTransaction(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1207)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.postInit(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl.<init>(EntityManagerImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:125)
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit of Neil;   "JtaStatusHelper is a HIBERNATE class!" rang the bell for me. I went and checked the props of emf as the following;

```
Map<String, Object> prop = emf.getProperties();
logger.debug("emf props : " + prop.toString());
```

And observed the differences between SIT and UAT environments. 
The basic difference was that openjpa was not available in any keys of the prop for SIT while it was all over the places for UAT.  The config for SIT was somehow turned into hibernate related lines. However, I was out after having things in place according to JPA settings.

It simply proved that something is wrong with the last installation of the application into Server. Thus, I uninstalled the app and install it from scratch. 
It made things right.